# How to filter items by id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, items

In a module, I need to deal with Order Items.

I know how to get items from Order:

```
$order = $this->_order->load($order_id);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
```

But I would like to retrieve the item using its ID, something like:

```
$item = $order->getAllItems()->filterById($item_id);
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the clean way exists :

```
$_item = $order->getItemById($_item_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct function for filtering the order items by `itemId`

But you can use a following loop based filter approach:

```
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $orderItem) {
    if($orderItem->getData('item_id') == $item_id) {
        $prodSku = $orderItem->getSku();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($prodSku);
    }
}
```

Inside the given `foreach` loop you can do your processing on the respective order-item.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: thank you for your answer. That's what I was doing, but was wondering if there was not a cleaner way...